# Updating Field value in multiple documents in same collection in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a chat app. In the app there is a collection named `Chat` and in it there are documents. Each document is a message that was sent and it contains fields such as `Message`, `SentTime`, `IsButton`.

Once something happens in the app (someone clicks a button), I had like to change in all of my documents at that chat the value of `IsButton` from `False` to `True`.

The data looks as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to change all of the `Field` values in one hit instead of using a loop?

I saw there is something called Batch however I'm not sure if it is limited to a maximum 500 updates.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to update multiple documents with a single API call.  You have to call out each document ID individually, and you can use a batch if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches you've found are pretty much the way to update a bunch of document.

You can:

- either update each document individually, which is not nearly as slow as you may think.
- or you can update the documents in one of more batches.

Having to update many documents with the same value may be a sign that you should reconsider your data structure. For example, maybe you can store the `IsButton` in a single, separate document that all clients then read/listen to.